# QListView wrapping very slow

Tags: qt, qlistview

I want to have a list view just like the one in Windows' file explorer: The data is shown into columns. So I set up a `QListView` with the code below.
It looks totally the same (see picture).

But one major drawback: When resizing the window, the wrapping is very slow. On the contrary, the Window's file browser is very fast.

How can I speed up the wrapping in the QListView?

[image]

h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QStandardItemModel* m=new QStandardItemModel;
    for (int i=100;i<1000;++i){
        m->insertRow(i-100,new QStandardItem(QString::number(i).repeated(5)+"   "));
    }
    ui->listView->setModel(m);
    ui->listView->setWrapping(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(e);
    ui->listView->setWrapping(ui->listView->isWrapping());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code under Linux with Qt 5.5.1 and wrapping is fast and instant.
What Qt version are you using? Qt 4.x has some performance issues under windows.

You can speed things up with `NoAntialias`

```
QFont fnt;
fnt.setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoAntialias);
ui->listView->setFont(fnt);
```

If your list grows bigger and you wan't to insert new data you will get bad performance. You should avoid QStandardItemModel for large sets of data.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.3. I tried my bigger main application with Qt 5.5 (upgraded from Qt 5.2), but some things were painfully slow (same code). So I installed Qt 5.3 that had the feature I wanted to use (initial motivation for the version upgrade). However, I made a test with Qt 5.5 now, and it wasn't instant, either. Also the 'NoAntialias' did not lead to any improvements :(

Comment: Now I also tried a very easy custom model (not a `QStandardItemModel` any more) but the result did not speed up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set wrapping every time the widget is resized. Qt is looking for the `isWrapping` property when resized and decides if a new segment is needed. You just need to set the `flow` property `LeftToRight` or `TopToBottom` and the `isWrapping` property once when the widget is created. Remove the code from the `resizeEvent`.
Also you can look at the `layoutMode` property for the performance purposes.